# ClassCastException when trying to set layout gravity to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a use-case when I need to change a linearlayout's gravity to center in parent programatically. For some reason it crashes :

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException
android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

I have the following xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/bg02" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            ...

            ...

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

code :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.weight = 1.0f;
                    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

myLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

- I also tried changing the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` since I thought it should be relative to the parent itself (which is RelativeLayout in this case) but that didn't change much..

Comment: check your imports.. probably you have imported wrong `LayoutParams`

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayout` is inside `RelativeLayout`, so must be `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: but(as I wrote at the end of the post) I tried it and it didn't help..
I replaced all LinearLayout.LayoutParams with RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: and besides that, when changing to RelativeLayout, I am unable to set gravity to params (and weight for that matter)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **RelativeLayout Param** instead of **LinearLayout param** and in RelativeLayout param you need to **add Rules** like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
   new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
//params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
//params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

Comment: it almost works.. half of the layout's content is aligned to the left.. and the margins that were defiend in the xml are emitted

Comment: When you add Layout param, it omits margin & padding which you have defined in xml.. so you need to add it again.

Comment: params.setMargins(0, 30, 0, 0);  // left, top, right, bottom

Comment: it seems the 'width' is emitted as well.. which method (if it all) can set the width ?

Comment: try this one: instead of MATCH_PARENT use your desired value..  
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
   new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 
                                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: that messes everything worse.. weird.. it cuts around 50dp of the layout and paces it at the center

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113591/discussion-between-mehta-and-bvtp).

Answer (score 0):

The Linearlayout is a child of a RelayiveLayout as pointed out by the previous responder. If you want to center the linear layout in the relativelayout, you can add rule as follows.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = myLinearLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
myLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Assuming that you want the linearlayout to be centered. If not, you can find the rule that suits your purpose.

Comment: the first line invokes an error : `incompatible types . Required : android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.  Found : android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams`